# How to access nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How to access nested dictionary in python. I want to access '**type**' of both card and card1.

```
data = {
'1': {
'type': 'card',
'card[number]': 12345,
},
'2': {
'type': 'wechat',
'name': 'paras'
}}
```

I want only type from both the dictionary. how can i get.
I use the following code but getting error:

```
>>> for item in data:
...     for i in item['type']: 
...             print(i)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
In [120]: for item in data.values():
     ...:     print(item['type'])

card
wechat
```

Or list comprehension:

```
In [122]: [item['type'] for item in data.values()]
Out[122]: ['card', 'wechat']
```

Comment: how to use using get().

Comment: You don't need to use `get()` here, but if you want, use `item.get('type')`

Answer (score 2):

When you iterate a dictionary, e.g. `for item in data`, you are iterating keys. You should use a view which contains the information you require, such as `dict.values` or `dict.items`.

To access the key and related type by iteration:

```
for k, v in data.items():
    print(k, v['item'])
```

Or, to create a list, use a list comprehension:

```
lst = [v['item'] for v in data.values()]
print(lst)
```

Answer (score -2):

[image: nested dict]

from a nested python dictionary like this, if I want to access lets, say article_url, so I have to program like this

```
[item['article_url'] for item in obj.values()]
```