# How to access dictionary values

Tags: python

I am trying to print dictionaries keys and values separately, the dictionary that've created consist of 2 values in a list: {'item':[val1,val2]}

How can i access the values separately?

This is my code where i tried to access the value of val1, but am getting both of val1 & val2

```
k=1
for i,j in toCart.items():
                print("(",k,")"," ",i,j)
                k += 1
```

Comment: In that code, `j[0]` is the first value and `j[1]` is the second.

Comment: Maybe using meaningful names instead of letters will help you navigate and understand your own code better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered here: [How to access nested dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507235/how-to-access-nested-dictionary-in-python)

Only instead of the second key you put the index

This kind of things are called nested dictionaries/lists
To call them, here is the syntax:

```
d[outer_dictionary_or_list][Inner_Dictionary_Or_List][And_So_On]
```

To get a list of dictionary keys, go here: [How to return dictionary keys as a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python)

To get a value from a key, do dictionary_name[key_name]